# svg.js with existing svg

Tags: svg, svg.js

I'm trying to implement svg.js to make a map of a clickable floorplan.
But I cannot make this work properly, or this works but doesn't work like I expected:

```
const map = SVG.get('mysvg');

map.click(function( event ) {

    this.fill({ color: '#000' });
    console.log(this);
    console.log(event.target);
});
```

When I try to click on some area on the map, instead of change fill color I get nothing.
Actually svgjs triggers 'create' as you can see in console with inspector.

Not sure what am I doing wrong here?
I would expect that the area will change fill color?

https://codepen.io/bobz-zg/pen/LdyXBe

Comment: do you have the pen for this? I think this whole question has gone stale, and it'd be good to update it with the latest version of svg.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the select function as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190326110753/http://svgjs.com/referencing/) to create a `Set`. You'd then use the `each()` method from `Set` to iterate over each entry and apply the click event handler. For example:

```
const map = SVG.get("mysvg");
var restaurants = map.select('[id*="restaurant"]:not(g)'); // Create an svg.js Set, but do not capture the group in the set

restaurants.each(function() {
  this.click(function(event) {
    this.fill({ color: "#000" });
  });
});
```

If you can edit the svg that you are using as an input, I would suggest adding a class to each of the clickable elements to use that as the reference for `select`. Otherwise, you'll have to do something like selecting all element id 'types' (i.e. restaurant, retail etc.) separately and concatenating the `Set`s using `Set.add()` before you do the loop to add the click listener, but that could get messy.

Comment: I suppose you could also just add an event listener to the document using vanilla js and then check the id/class attribute before applying the fill. It might even be easier than using svg.js if that is the only thing you intend to do with that library.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but for some reason 'this.fill' is not working to me at all. I've tried with adopt and get methods but I can catch only click events. Might better use vanilla then break my head with this.

Comment: Right sorry it is working, I had css overwriting my style but I can see in dom that attribute is added.

Comment: Right, there is something funny going on with this. Now with exact same code after some time, click is not triggering. I'll better switch to vanialla

Comment: Right one more time. Looks like events not fetched if 'fill: none' in css.

Comment: css always overwites html attributes. Thats no error with the library or whatsoever. If you want fill:none as default just set it at element creation or you dont change the fill attribute but instead change the style attribute like `this.style({fill: "#000"})`. Beside that I think `SVG.Set` supports using `click` on it directly. So no need for `each`